# Java Serialization readObject input vs readExternal input

Tags: java, serializable

The signature for readObject is:

```
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

which takes in a reference of a concrete class type.

The signature for readExternal is:

```
void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
```

which takes in a reference of an interface type.

So why this discrepency? Is it just an oversight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectInputStream` has several methods not in `ObjectInput` that are used specifically to support the default serialization mechanism. Therefore, serialization needs to come from an `ObjectInputStream`, but externalization can come from any `ObjectInput`.